# How do I represent this complex json document as a C# object?

Tags: c#, json, object, json.net

I would like to create a C# base object class that represents the Json document below(which is a questionnaire form). I can do the first three three lines easily but how do I do the nested ones from `"FormBody": { }` on wards.

I have seen where guys use `public IDictionary<string, object> FormBody {get; set;}`. Can I pass this in to Json.Net and let it populate the object class for me? Or are there other ways?

```
{
  "FormTitle": "Product 27",
  "FormId": "CCC12345",
  "Type": "forms",
  "FormBody": {
    "image": {
      "width": 450,
      "height": 200,
      "title": "ACME Insurance",
      "location": "Images/Forms/sample.jpg"
    },
    "heading1": {
      "text": "Commercial Crime"
    },
    "body1": {
      "text": "Important Notice, It is important that you as the proposer provide full and detailed answers to all the questions to enable the insurer to properly assess the risk involved and that the quote will be fair"
    },
    "heading2": {
      "text": "How to use this form"
    },
    "body2": {
      "text": "Please answer the questions listed below by either selecting an answer from the provided list/ contorl or enter the information into the designated field"
    },
    "categories": [
      {
        "name": "Gerenal Information",
        "questions": [
          {
            "questionNumber": "1",
            "dependencyLevel": {
              "question": "0",
              "answer": "0"
            },
            "questionText": "Are there any subsidiary companies that need to be included?",
            "answerOptions": {
              "control": {
                "type": "groupCheckBox",
                "selectionOptions": {
                  "availibleSelectionAmount": "2",
                  "options": [
                    "Yes",
                    "No"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "selectedAnswer": {
              "selection": "Yes"
            }
          },
          {
            "questionNumber": "1.1",
            "dependencyLevel": {
              "question": "1",
              "answer": "Yes"
            },
            "questionText": "How many subsidiaries need to be included?",
            "questionInformation": {
              "text": "Please enter a number"
            },
            "answerOptions": {
              "control": {
                "type": "dropDownList",
                "selectionOptions": {
                  "availibleSelectionAmount": "5",
                  "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4",
                    "5"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "selectedAnswer": {
              "selection": "1"
            }
          },
          {
            "questionNumber": "1.2",
            "dependencyLevel": {
              "question": "1",
              "answer": "Yes"
            },
            "questionText": "Does the proposer have branches, subsidiaries, entities which are based outside RSA?",
            "questionInformation": {
              "text": "Please select one of the following"
            },
            "answerOptions": {
              "control": {
                "type": "groupCheckBox",
                "selectionOptions": {
                  "availibleSelectionAmount": "2",
                  "options": [
                    "Yes",
                    "No"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "selectedAnswer": {
              "selection": "No"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "HR",
        "questions": [
          {
            "questionNumber": "2",
            "dependencyLevel": {
              "question": "0",
              "answer": "0"
            },
            "questionText": "How often does someone who is not normally involved in the payroll's update and preperation check on the payroll?",
            "questionInformation": {
              "text": "Please select one from the list"
            },
            "answerOptions": {
              "control": {
                "type": "dropDownList",
                "selectionOptions": {
                  "availibleSelectionAmount": "5",
                  "options": [
                    "At least ounce a month",
                    "At least ounce a quater",
                    "At least every 6 months",
                    "Less than ounce a month",
                    "Less often"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "selectedAnswer": {
              "selection": "At least ounce a month"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Accounting",
        "information": "An owner/manger is an individual who owns most of the proposers shares and runs the business",
        "questions": [
          {
            "questionNumber": "3",
            "dependencyLevel": {
              "question": "0",
              "answer": "0"
            },
            "questionText": "Does the proposer's processes allow for someone to make payments without the owner/manager's knowledge",
            "questionInformation": {
              "text": "Please select one from the list"
            },
            "answerOptions": {
              "control": {
                "type": "dropDownList",
                "selectionOptions": {
                  "availibleSelectionAmount": "5",
                  "options": [
                    "At least ounce a month",
                    "At least ounce a quater",
                    "At least every 6 months",
                    "Less than ounce a month",
                    "Less often"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "selectedAnswer": {
              "selection": "At least ounce a month"
            }
          },
          {
            "questionNumber": "3.1",
            "dependencyLevel": {
              "question": "3",
              "answer": "2"
            },
            "questionText": "Is dual authority required for EFTs?",
            "questionInformation": {
              "text": "Please select one"
            },
            "answerOptions": {
              "control": {
                "type": "checkBox",
                "selectionOptions": {
                  "availibleSelectionAmount": "2",
                  "options": [
                    "Yes",
                    "No"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "selectedAnswer": {
              "selection": "Yes"
            }
          },
          {
            "questionNumber": "3.2",
            "dependencyLevel": {
              "question": "3.1",
              "answer": "Yes"
            },
            "questionText": "Are the people loading and releasing the payments both to check that the payments are made against a suitible authorisation document(e.g. signed purchase order, delivery note or similar)?",
            "questionInformation": {
              "text": "Please select one"
            },
            "answerOptions": {
              "control": {
                "type": "checkBox",
                "selectionOptions": {
                  "availibleSelectionAmount": "2",
                  "options": [
                    "Yes",
                    "No"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "selectedAnswer": {
              "selection": "Yes"
            }
          },
          {
            "questionNumber": "4",
            "dependencyLevel": {
              "question": "0",
              "answer": "0"
            },
            "questionText": "Does the proposer have an annual formal budgeting process and is management approval required for payments which fall outside the budget?",
            "questionInformation": {
              "text": "Please select one from the list"
            },
            "answerOptions": {
              "control": {
                "type": "dropDownList",
                "selectionOptions": {
                  "availibleSelectionAmount": "4",
                  "options": [
                    "No formal budget",
                    "Yes, there is a budget but it is a guideline only and is not strictly enforced",
                    "Yes, there is a formal budget and any deviations require managemant approval",
                    "Yes, there is a formal budget but small purchases outside the budget do not require management approval"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "selectedAnswer": {
              "selection": "Yes, there is a formal budget and any deviations require managemant approval"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Cash",
        "questons": [
          {
            "questionNumber": "5",
            "dependencyLevel": {
              "question": "0",
              "answer": "0"
            },
            "questionText": "What is the typical maximum amount of cash and near cash on hand at any one time? This includes petty cash, payments by debtors, creditor's payments, etc. Near cash includes coins and negotiables such as cheques, etc.",
            "questionInformation": {
              "text": "Please select one from the list"
            },
            "answerOptions": {
              "control": {
                "type": "dropDownList",
                "selectionOptions": {
                  "availibleSelectionAmount": "5",
                  "options": [
                    "Less than R 50,000",
                    "Less than R 100,000",
                    "Less than R 250,000",
                    "Less than R 2,500,000",
                    "More than R 2,500,000"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "selectedAnswer": {
              "selection": "More than R 2,500,000"
            }
          },
          {
            "questionNumber": "5.1",
            "dependencyLevel": {
              "question": "5",
              "answer": "More than R 2,500,000"
            },
            "questionText": "Is the proposer paid in cash for goods/services?",
            "questionInformation": {
              "text": "Please select one from the list"
            },
            "answerOptions": {
              "control": {
                "type": "dropDownList",
                "selectionOptions": {
                  "availibleSelectionAmount": "5",
                  "options": [
                    "Never",
                    "Less than once a month",
                    "Somethimes",
                    "Often",
                    "Very Often"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "selectedAnswer": {
              "selection": "Very Often"
            }
          },
          {
            "questionNumber": "5.1.1",
            "dependencyLevel": {
              "question": "5.1",
              "answer": "4"
            },
            "questionText": "How often are cash reconciliations done?",
            "questionInformation": {
              "text": "Please select one from the list"
            },
            "answerOptions": {
              "control": {
                "type": "dropDownList",
                "selectionOptions": {
                  "availibleSelectionAmount": "5",
                  "options": [
                    "Never",
                    "Less than once a month",
                    "Somethimes",
                    "Often",
                    "Very Often"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "selectedAnswer": {
              "selection": "Often"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class MyJson
{
    [DataMember(Name="FormTitle", IsRequired = true)]
    public string FormTitle { get; set; }

    ...

    [DataMember(Name="FormBody", IsRequired = true)]
    public FormBody fb { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public sealed class FormBody
{
    [DataMember(Name="image", IsRequired = true)]
    public Image img { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And so on and so on. You can create a class for each complex type in your JSon (Strings and String[] are there to be used directly).

How to serialize:

```
var jsonString = ...

var json = new DataContractJsonSerializer (typeof(MyJson));
var stream = new MemoryStream (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (jsonString));
var myObj = (MyJson)json.ReadObject (stream);
stream.Close ();
```

How to deserialize:

```
FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create (filepath);

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream ();
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer (typeof(MyJson));

jsonSerializer.WriteObject (stream, myObj);
stream.Position = 0;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (stream);

string jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd ();
```

Comment: ah, the namespace used is `System.Runtime.Serialization`

Comment: So how would you do the classes I have listed in my answer?

Comment: I showed you the beginning - Strings `FormTitle`, `FormId`, `Type` as fields of the "main" class, then the complex type `FormBody` (separate class) consisting of - `heading1`, `body1`, `heading2`, `body2`, each of them containing `String text` as the only field - which means you can create one class and use it as type for all four...

I hope I made myself clear.. look closely at your json and you will see how to model it.

But don't expect the other ones to write code for you :)

Comment: I do not expect that at all, but thanks for the help non the less

Answer (score 0):

I have just found this [website](http://json2csharp.com/) that create the object classes for you but are they correct?

```
public class Image
{
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
}

public class Heading1
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Body1
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Heading2
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Body2
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class DependencyLevel
{
    public string question { get; set; }
    public string answer { get; set; }
}

public class SelectionOptions
{
    public string availibleSelectionAmount { get; set; }
    public List<string> options { get; set; }
}

public class Control
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public SelectionOptions selectionOptions { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerOptions
{
    public Control control { get; set; }
}

public class SelectedAnswer
{
    public string selection { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionInformation
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public string questionNumber { get; set; }
    public DependencyLevel dependencyLevel { get; set; }
    public string questionText { get; set; }
    public AnswerOptions answerOptions { get; set; }
    public SelectedAnswer selectedAnswer { get; set; }
    public QuestionInformation questionInformation { get; set; }
}

public class DependencyLevel2
{
    public string question { get; set; }
    public string answer { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionInformation2
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class SelectionOptions2
{
    public string availibleSelectionAmount { get; set; }
    public List<string> options { get; set; }
}

public class Control2
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public SelectionOptions2 selectionOptions { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerOptions2
{
    public Control2 control { get; set; }
}

public class SelectedAnswer2
{
    public string selection { get; set; }
}

public class Queston
{
    public string questionNumber { get; set; }
    public DependencyLevel2 dependencyLevel { get; set; }
    public string questionText { get; set; }
    public QuestionInformation2 questionInformation { get; set; }
    public AnswerOptions2 answerOptions { get; set; }
    public SelectedAnswer2 selectedAnswer { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Question> questions { get; set; }
    public string information { get; set; }
    public List<Queston> questons { get; set; }
}

public class FormBody
{
    public Image image { get; set; }
    public Heading1 heading1 { get; set; }
    public Body1 body1 { get; set; }
    public Heading2 heading2 { get; set; }
    public Body2 body2 { get; set; }
    public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string FormTitle { get; set; }
    public string FormId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public FormBody FormBody { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes that looks correct. Your JSON is just a bunch of objects within other objects. To translate this to c# you must declare the classes so you can have a reference to an object of that type from another object.

Comment: ok I see what you are saying, so heading 1 is a type of Form body?