# Creating a class for de/serializing

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON string like:

```
var json = "{\"Attributes\": {\"name\":\"S1\", \"quantity\":\"100\"}}";
```

I want to design a class for the same; how does one approach while creating a class for JSON string in C# ?

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Your Json is not valid

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012, go in the menu to *EDIT -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As CLasses*.

You valid JSON should probably look like this (you should remove the `\` before copying it to the clipboard):

```
{"Attributes": {"name":"S1", "quantity":"100"}}
```

The generated classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Attributes
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Sample usage (note that the `\` is still here, in order to have valid code syntax):

```
var json = "{\"Attributes\": {\"name\":\"S1\", \"quantity\":\"100\"}}";
var json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
Rootobject dc = json_serializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(json);
```

Comment: +1, didn't even realize that VS had this built-in out of the box. -- AND xml, oh snap!

Comment: @alex I am doing the following 
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
RootObject dc = json_serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(str);
However dc is still showing null

Answer (score 0):

You're question's unclear, but I assume you mean parsing JSON in to C# objects? Using JSON.NET and something like this can do that:

```
public class Attributes
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quantity")]
    public Int32 Quantity { get; set; }
}
public class MyObject
{
    [JsonProperty("Attributes")]
    public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
}

var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```

Or you can go more broadly and let JSON.NET do it for you:

```
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(
   "{ \"Attributes\": {\"name\":\"S1\", \"quantity\":\"100\"}}"
 );
 Console.WriteLine(obj.Attributes["name"])     // S1
 Console.WriteLine(obj.Attributes["quantity"]) // 100
```

Comment: whenever I try to use JSON.NET in my websevice(IIS) my client always gets a Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the namespace `System.Runtime.Serialization`, you can find useful classes for (de)serializing JSON there

also you can read this similar question (searching before posting does not really hurt):

[How do I represent this complex json document as a C# object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344114/how-do-i-represent-this-complex-json-document-as-a-c-sharp-object/17344455#17344455)